# OpenCv ssize.area()>0 error on small images

Tags: python, opencv

I have searched a lot on it but this error comes mostly when the images are large. My images are not large and I'm still getting this error. I am trying to recognize handwritten digits via openCV.I have checked that my images are being loaded or not so that is not issue. Here is my code.

```
im = cv2.imread(filename,1)
    # Convert to grayscale and apply Gaussian filtering
    # Convert image from one color space to another
    im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    im_gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(im_gray, (5, 5), 0)
    # Threshold to binary the image
    ret, im_th = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    # Find contours in the image
    _, ctrs, hier = cv2.findContours(im_th.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    # Get rectangles contains each contour
    rects = [cv2.boundingRect(ctr) for ctr in ctrs]

    # For each rectangular region, calculate HOG features and predict
    # the digit using Linear SVM.
    for rect in rects:
        # Draw the rectangles
        cv2.rectangle(im, (rect[0], rect[1]), (rect[0] + rect[2], rect[1] + rect[3]), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        # Make the rectangular region around the digit
        leng = int(rect[3] * 1.6)
        pt1 = int(rect[1] + rect[3] // 2 - leng // 2)
        pt2 = int(rect[0] + rect[2] // 2 - leng // 2)
        roi = im_th[pt1:pt1+leng, pt2:pt2+leng]
        # Resize the image
        roi = cv2.resize(roi, (28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
        roi = cv2.dilate(roi, (3, 3))
        # Calculate the HOG features
        roi_hog_fd = hog(roi, orientations=9, pixels_per_cell=(14, 14), cells_per_block=(1, 1), visualise=False)
        nbr = clf.predict(np.array([roi_hog_fd], 'float64'))
```

I have doubt on these two lines that they are from where the error emerges.

```
ret, im_th = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 90, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

and

```
roi = cv2.resize(roi, (28, 28), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
```

it is also not accepting paint images. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that for every `rect` close to a border of your image, your computation of `pt1` or `pt2` gives a **negative** result because of the enlarged *ROI* (green box on my picture).

[image: ROI out of image bounds]

SO, I would recommend to check whether `pt1` and `pt2` are positive. If not I would set them to `0` and recompute the *ROI*'s size accordingly.